# Knowing which fonts are installed

Tags: java, android, fonts

In my Androïd application, I want to let the user select the font he wants. For this, I need to show him a list containing each and every font currently loaded on the device.

So far, I haven't been able to find a way to get this list. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible?

Your user can choose sans serif, serif, or monospace, plus any fonts that you bundle in with your app or that you download. There is no "list" of fonts on the device, simply because there are no fonts on the device available for SDK applications except sans serif, serif, and monospace.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me how to bundle a font in my application?

Comment: @Zelig: Create an `assets/` directory in your project, as a peer of `res/`, `src/`, etc. Put a TrueType font file in there (OpenType may now work, but it did not used to work back in 2008). Then use the `Typeface` class to get a `Typeface` object, which you can apply to your `TextView` (or subclasses) via `setTypeface()`. Here is a sample project demonstrating this: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Fonts/FontSampler Note that not all fonts seem to work, and rather than giving an error, it simply uses Droid Sans by default.